# What do the letters RFF stand for (it's a finite field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

In abstract algebra, the set $\{0, 2, 4, 6, 8\}$, equipped with addition and multiplication mod $10$, is sometimes given as an example of a finite field. In that context it is called RFF. (It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$). What does the name mean? There must be some history here.

See, for example, this mention: https://books.google.ie/books?id=LBNREAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2

Comment: This notation is not very frequent. I found "Residue finite field", but also "Rational function field", but this is not suitable here. Residue field is a quotient field of a ring $R$ modulo an ideal $I$, so for example $\Bbb Z/(p)$.

Comment: I've never seen this name before in my life and this book itself is the only reference I can find to it.

Comment: Thanks. It occurs in some lecture notes distributed for a course I'm taking in Abstract Algebra. I think this is unconnected to the book linked to above, so that's two instances of the term at least.